# Add a subview to a custom class UIViewController that loads from nib, in Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, xib

To clarify on this ridiculous title:

I'm using my own subclass of JSQMessagesViewController (https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) - let's call it ACMessagesViewController. I'm loading my ACMessagesViewController through storyboard, by setting the storyboard UIViewController's custom class to ACMessagesViewController. I am trying to add a subview to ACMessagesViewController's view through the storyboard.

JSQMessagesViewController loads from a nib. When I add a subview to ACMessagesViewController's view through storyboard, the view disappears. The subview seems to be adding to a view other than my ACMessagesViewController's self.view, and by the time the viewdidload scope runs through, the subview is gone.

My questions are:
1. What is the proper way to add a subview (through storyboard) to a custom class UIViewController, when the UIViewController loads from a nib?
2. What is happening in this view loading process? Why is my subview (added through storyboard) adding onto a view that is not the same self.view in my ACMessagesViewController?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean your view is being drawn on the screen and then removed, or that it never draws at all?

Comment: I never see it onscreen, and it's gone (null) by the time view did appear is called. Its super view is a view that is not the viewcontroller's self.view

Comment: Do you think it's possible the JSQMessagesViewController is programatically creating its own views and in the process, disconnecting the view you created in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what's happening. But I'm not sure on how that cycle works. Trying to learn more about it and also see if there's a way to load  from nib while also adding views through storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's one of those "if you need to work around it, you're probably doing it wrong" scenarios you so often hit in iOS development. :-) Really, if you want the functionality the JSQMessagesViewController provides, you shouldn't need to add additional views.  But if you must add views, the "right" way to do it is to add them as subviews of whatever self.view is after you call super in viewDidLoad.  If you don't want to construct views programmatically, you can put them in a separate nib (instead of the storyboard) and manually load them.

(Note: this is assuming viewDidLoad is getting called.  If it isn't, you might need to hook into some other method.)

Comment: I ended up going the programmatic route. Was just wondering if there was something to learn about storyboards and view loading here.

Comment: I had the same issue. The problem seems to be that JSQMessagesViewController uses an unconventional way of loading its views. It should be possible to do what you want without loading a second nib. Just... not with this particular library.

Comment: I will answer  your question number 2) since  Anna left it unanswered.
The reason this doesn't work is that you have this:

1) superclass + superclass.nib
2) subclass + subclass.nib

When you initialise, what you get is

subclass + superclass.nib

But you added your view to subclass.nib which is simply ignored.

Answer (score -2):

I used @Anna's suggestion to add the view in `viewDidLoad` but you don't need to use a second Xib or design the view in code.
What you need is:

A. Design your view in the your `JSQMessagesViewController` scene in the storyboard/xib file.

B. Create an outlet of the view you need to present.

C. In `viewDidLoad` add your view with `view.addSubview(myView)` (or `[self.view addSubview:self.myView]` for all the objc ones out there)

D. That's it!